# What is the error in my shiny app that shows an iframe?

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I want to use an iframe inside a shiny app. I am new to R and shiny. This is my code:

```
library(shinyLP)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    htmlOutput("frame")    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    output$frame <- renderUI({
      link <- "http://www.ogame.de"
      Frame <- tags$iframe(width = "1042", height = "823", url_link = link)
      Frame
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I run the app in the frame is "Not Found" instead of google. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(shinyLP)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    htmlOutput("frame")    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$frame <- renderUI({
    link <- "http://www.ogame.de"
    Frame <- iframe(width = "1042", height = "823", url_link = link)
    Frame
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

(Open it with the browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
Put the link into the tags, like so:

    server <- function(input, output,session) {

      output$frame <- renderUI({
        Frame <- tags$iframe(src = "http://www.ogame.de",width = "1042", height = "823")
        Frame
      }) 
}
```

You don’t need the `shinyLP`package to show an iFrame.